# find a graphic card that suits a specific motherboard

Tags: graphics, hardware

I want to search for a graphic card that suits my motherboard, but I don't know how!
For example, I have this [motherboard](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1218&MenuID=103&LanID=0), I don't know which type of graphic card should I search for.

Comment: I would recommend as a first step reading the SO Helpcentre.  Once this is done I would hope that you become aware that this is not the right place for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Answer your question, it just depends on your budget and how much power your POWER SUPPLY can handle. ECS is not considered a high end motherboard manufacturer but it really don't matter.

The Graphics card is just like a CPU, it requires power, a lot of it at times. When a game runs, it heavily depends on the GPU to run the game which draws a lot of power. As you can see on your motherboard it has a 16x PCI express card, meaning it will take basically ANY card that supports x16 PCI express.

EXPANSION SLOT  1 x PCI Express x16 Gen2.0 slot <<--- here

Now your only problem is determining how much power you need. i'd recommend getting getting a power supply that has at least 2 -> 6 pin plugs (you can google that) and is at least 600 watts of power or more to support any graphics card you buy.

Answer (score 0):

It has a built-in graphics card. See the photo on the link you sent. VGA and DVI, see also the specs under rear panel I/o. If you insist on another graphics card, Google "pci graphics card". Your motherboard has 4 PCI slots. Read the spec.

By the way, this question is not appropriate for stackoverflow. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Totally useless help sir! I know about built-in graphic card on my motherboard!(I'm working with that!) And I Know the mother-board has  PCI slots. I don't know why you don't answer my question and did your way! I want to know how can I check the maximum compatibility of graphic card and motherboard. You had better know that all of graphics card cant match all other motherboard smarty.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. Your question was rather vague.

Comment: @dynamo The correct response to such questions is to down-vote and possibly flag for closure.